# "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Tags: java, xml, string, int, boolean

I'm getting this error:

> error: method createOrderSummary in class MainActivity cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: int,boolean
>
> found: int
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Here's my code:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

    int price = calculatePrice();
    String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(int price)
    displayMessage(priceMessage);
```

}

```
private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean addWhippedCream) {
String priceMessage = "Name: Samantha";
priceMessage += "\nAdd Whipped Cream?" + addWhippedCream;
priceMessage += "\nQuantity: " + quantity;
priceMessage += "\nTotal: $" + price;
priceMessage += "\nThank You!";
return priceMessage;
```

The issue, I believe, started with adding the boolean variable to the String. I don't understand why the boolean variable  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well it sounds like you're calling it without specifying a value for the `addWhippedCream` parameter, e.g. `foo.createOrderSummary(10);`. You can't call a method without supplying values for all the parameters.

Comment: Show the invocation of this method. The error states that you didn't pass second argument at all. In Java parameters don't have default values, so addWhippedCream is undefined unless you explicitly pass value to it.

Answer (score 0):

pass these values. you're only passing int i guess.
Example

calling a function

```
createOrderSummary(20, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call on the method should look like this:

```
string SomeString = createOrderSummary(10, true);
```

the Error you are getting basically sais that the call you made is missing a parameter (probably in your Main method):

```
//this is wrong. The second argument is missing. 
string SomeString = createOrderSummary(10);
```

And by the way. You can't just add a string and a boolean. You would have to convert the boolean first.

```
boolean addWhippedCream = true;
String str = String.valueOf(addWhippedCream);
System.out.println("The String is: "+ str);
```

or

```
System.out.println("The String is :" + String.valueOf(addWhippedCream));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method that you pasted needs to be inside of a class, so I'll embed it in one:

```
class A{
    private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean addWhippedCream) {
         String priceMessage = "Name: Samantha";
         priceMessage += "\nAdd Whipped Cream?" + addWhippedCream;
         priceMessage += "\nQuantity: " + quantity;
         priceMessage += "\nTotal: $" + price;
         priceMessage += "\nThank You!";
         return priceMessage;
    }
}
```

To call(invoke) it you need to create an object of class `A` and then call this method for that object.

For instance:

```
A a = new A();
a.createOrderSummary(10, true);
new A().createOrderSummary(5, false);
```

you may save the result of such invocation:

```
string result1 = a.createOrderSummary(10, true);
string result2 = new A().createOrderSummary(5, false);
```